# How do I store additional data based on user submitted form in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to extract and save EXIF data for an uploaded image. For the form I use

```
<?php

namespace Timeline\DefaultBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Timeline\DefaultBundle\Form\EventListener\DocumentListener;

class DocumentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file')
            ->add('upload', 'submit')
            ->addEventSubscriber(new DocumentListener());
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Timeline\DefaultBundle\Entity\Document',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'document';
    }
}
```

And then I have a listener class:

```
<?php


namespace Timeline\DefaultBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;



class DocumentListener implements EventSubscriberInterface{



    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT     => 'onPostSubmit'
        );
    }

    public function onPostSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $form->add('exif','collection',array('data' => array("a" => 'some data',"b" => "some data","c" => "some data")));
    }
```

The problem I have is that if I use `POST_SUBMIT` I get the error **You cannot add children to a submitted form**

If I use `PRE_SUBMIT` it stores the keys but not the data `{"a":null,"b":null,"c":null}`

How I add that EXIF data after the file was uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

like so:

```
$event->getForm()->getParent()
```

you need to basically add the fields to the form's parent.  So the following should work:

```
    public function onPostSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm()->getParent();

        $form->add('exif','collection',array('data' => array("a" => 'some data',"b" => "some data","c" => "some data")));
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but I get ```FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object in ```

Comment: have you looked at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

Comment: yes, but there the data is another entity. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with my code - just trying to save an array.

Comment: if the data is in another entity, couldn't you just pass in that entity as an argument when constructing the formtype?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `$formModifier` callback, in your `buildForm` try to include this:

```
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form) {
    $form->add('exif','collection',array('data' => array("a" => 'some data',"b" => "some data","c" => "some data")));
};

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
    $formModifier($event->getForm());
});
```

`FormModifier` explained in more detail at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

-- Edit

For this to work you would need the following use statements

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
```

Also if you are going with this approach you can remove your

```
->addEventSubscriber(new DocumentListener())
```

On your initial `$builder` call